# Vue.js if statement with two variables

Tags: vue.js

I need to check if the current user is the author of the question to allow him to see/use the delete question button.
But with my implementation I can´t see the button at all:

```html
<form @submit.prevent="deleteQuestion(question.id)">
    <input type="submit" v-if="this.currentUser === question.author" value="Löschen"/>
</form>
```

I get question.author with a JSON request , currentUser is set during the login.

Thanks for taking the time,

Fierl.

Answer (score 0):

`this.currentUser` and `question.author` are not the same objects, even though they might contain the same data. This is why the comparison fails.

Your user objects probably have an `id` property (or some other primary key). Compare against that instead.

```html
<input type="submit" v-if="this.currentUser.id === question.author.id" value="Löschen"/>
```

Comment: thanks, but if i don´t have an id for both of them? can I cast them somehow?

Comment: If you not have any kind of unique key to compare them against (ID, username, email, etc), then there's no way you can compare them. You might be able to do a [deep comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript) of the objects instead, if that works for you.